# Is there any visualization techniques to solve time complexity problems?

Tags: algorithms

Say problems like this. I am not looking to the solution of this problem alone. I am looking for a mindset of visualization that you have devised as a trick for yourself.

**Find the value of q in terms of n?**

```
function fun(n) {
  let i,
    j,
    p,
    q = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    p = 0;
    for (j = n; j > 1; j = j / 2) {
      ++p;
    }
    for (k = 1; k < p; k = k * 2) {
      ++q;
    }
  }
  return q;
}

let val_q = fun(36);
console.log(val_q);
```

I want to learn how to learn it.

Like is there some visualization techniques that you've devised that helps in solving these kind of problems by hand.

Comment: The huge observation here is that the value of `i` is never used in the inner loops.

Comment: By ["visualization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_and_information_visualization), do you mean [plotting the time it takes the algorithm to run on different input sizes](https://dev.to/chroline/visualizing-algorithm-runtimes-in-python-f92) to see how it scales, or are you referring more to mental strategies for figuring it out? If the latter, I wouldn't use the word "visualization" as it generally refers to plotting/charting stuff, I think.

Comment: Honestly  it could be anything

Comment: This seems a poor exercise to me.  I can't tell exactly what it's doing, but I can see that it's doing it in a nonsensically roundabout way.